# How safe are proxies if your IP could be cross-referenced?

Tags: security, proxy, privacy

Let's say you're the NSA. And let's say you have "backdoor" access (for the sake of this discussion we'll assume that includes at a minimum the mapping of an IP address to a logged-in user) to Google.

Now, let's say I want to engage in an activity that I am highly inclined to NOT be identified with (like leaking some sensitive documents to a journalist).

My first thought would be "use a proxy" because it'll change my IP address to some random location in Canada, or Germany. Better yet a country which will not share logs with U.S. LEA.

But, let's say I'm logged into Google in a separate browser. Or hell, just have my Gmail account connected to my desktop mail program (Apple Mail, for example). As soon as I connect to that proxy, and my next request for mail goes to Google, Google could theoretically have a log of my proxied IP address to my Google account. Even if we pretend that all of my mail and any actual requests I made are end-to-end encrypted, there's potentially still a mapping of 12.123.123.123 (my proxied IP) -> Rob Cameron in their logs somewhere.

So, if you (the NSA) were to somehow get your hands on any requests made to my journalist friend (the site I'm uploading files to, or a chat engine, some kind of man-in-the-middle attack) couldn't you cross-reference that IP with the Google one? One [FISA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_Intelligence_Surveillance_Act) request to Google for the real identify of Rob Cameron and I'm screwed.

It's easy to say "don't be logged into Google" but won't any modern operating system be pinging *some* service somewhere occasionally? Even if I closed all other applications besides a single browser window, Apple is still pinging iCloud and Windows is still pinging Microsoft and even Linux is still hitting an NTP service somewhere.

Are there any options for being truly anonymous with a "mainstream" OS? Is something like [Tails](https://tails.boum.org/) your only option? Or am I being paranoid and a [good proxy](https://airvpn.org) is actually a great option?

Comment: NSA is going to find you regardless of the method you choose. Better put your tinfoil hat on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you are concerned about government level surveillance the problem you identified is a very real threat.

Normally what someone will do in this situation is boot in to a "clean" OS that has no personal identifying information on it ([Tails](https://tails.boum.org) is a good example of this) and only use it for that anonymous communication. You could do it with Windows, it is important that you do not have any personally identifiable information tied to the os install. You would have to pirate your copy, your Windows activation with enough effort could be tied to back to you and if you are worried about a government killing you for the information you are releasing I honestly think that is already WAY too much information on the OS that could be tied back to you and accidently released.

You really need to treat it as if the person you are trying to keep the secret from has full 100% access to the entire hard drive. And honestly, for organizations like the NSA they just might, they may know a website you will visit to share the info, infect it with a 0-day virus, cause you to be infected and have full access to see all files on the computer.

It is safer to just use a OS designed to not release or have information about you like Tails, also due to the virus risk you should use an entirely new computer (bought used, with cash) to do it.

---

Whether or not you actually need to be concerned about government level surveillance is up to you.

Comment: Is it safe to run Tails inside a VM? Should it always be a completely standalone machine with its own connection to your router? Is it even safe to run that machine inside a network with other non-proxied machines?

Comment: Are people trying to kill you to stop the information from getting out? If yes then it is not safe to run in a VM, it should be a completely standalone machine, and you should NEVER run the machine inside a network associated with you, even if you are using proxies. For the VM, there are ways to break out of a VM and see in to the "real" hard drive, dual booting is not a solution either because if someone gets 100% access to the machine due to a exploit serial numbers on hardware can identifiy you.

Comment: If you connect the machine to your home network other machines (including your router) may see and remember that they saw the machine. A totalitarian government agency can  easily bust down your door and look at other machines you own to see if if you are a "associate" of the leaker they are looking for. If they see traces of evidence that the machine that sent the leak was at your house at some point in time in the past they have a reason to send you to their secret prison. I know i am taking the examples to the extreme but you seem to want to know the "worst case possible"

Comment: What about running Tails in a remote machine and SSHing to it? Is the best option to carry around a Raspberry Pi with Tails installed, going to an internet cafe hundreds of miles from your house and only then connecting and performing these activities?

Comment: If you are concerned about the level of thread you claim you are you need to act like the people trying to find out who you are are sitting next to you watching everything you do while you do it. Do you think it is safe to let the attacker watch you (not an anonymous person, **YOU**) SSH to a box, then while you have the SSH connection open see that the box had a anonymous person send the leaked info?

Comment: The best option is to use a Raspberry Pi bought with cash anonymously with Tails installed then going to an internet cafe hundreds of miles from your house to do your stuff, then you destroy everything, never go to the cafe again and never make a 2nd drop (the more often you do this the more data you share about yourself, they can figure out where you live by using the drop sites you picked. They do this all the time with serial killers and is a very well practiced science)

Answer (score 0):

another option could be as simple (if you're on windows anyway) as using firefox for your illicit tasks.

It has separate proxy settings from the rest of your system, so your OS and other apps etc can connect directly or via some differnent proxy to the proxy your browser uses.

A local proxy could also be another option, since you then can control how connections are made.  For example our product [WinGate](http://www.wingate.com) will allow you to specify different upstream proxies on a request-by-request basis (or on any other basis).

Disclaimer: I work for Qbik who are the authors of WinGate